# Android studio IDE error in project

Tags: android

I am having trouble with my Android Studio.

I get a bunch of errors without me having written a line of code. I just installed it and it can't find alot of things. I have added an screenshot of the screen i get.

I hope anyone can help me fix this. I just got a new laptop.

[Errors in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Psagj.png)

Comment: Remove the underscore

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Underscore in your package name and try to build a new project.